# Correct version in mix.exs dependency declaration

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have a `mix.exs` file that has some dependencies:

```
def deps do
    [{:nadia, "~> 0.4"}]
end
```

Let's say I want to change Nadia to version `0.3`. I'm having a hard time doing that.

After making the change to `mix.exs`, I can't get the version 0.3 for Nadia. Neither `mix deps.update` nor `mix deps.unlock && mix deps.update` help me.

I'm sure there's a way to do this; I just couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to switch to 0.3 or 3.0?

Comment: @Dogbert to 0.3. Fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the requirement `~> 0.3` gives you `0.4.0` is because `~> 0.3` is equivalent to `>= 0.3.0 and < 1.0.0` ([ref](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Version.html)). If you want `>= 0.3.0 and < 0.4.0`, you need to use the requirement `~> 0.3.0`:

```
def deps do
  [{:nadia, "~> 0.3.0"}]
end
```

A simple `mix deps.get` after changing your `mix.exs` will give you the latest `0.3.x` version of `nadia`. There's no need to run `mix deps.unlock` or `mix deps.update`.

Comment: I tried, but Mix spell this out to me: `Dependency resolution completed: nadia: 0.4.0 All dependencies up to date`

Comment: Are you sure you have `{:nadia, "~> 0.3.0"}` in your mix.exs?